# Trying to make a CLI tool in Java work

Tags: java, command-line-interface

So this is my code:

```
package ca.wax.main;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Wax {

static String commands[];

public static void main(String[]args){
    CommandMethods cm = new CommandMethods();
    commands = new String[3];
    int stringLength = commands.length;
    commands[0] = "deauth";
    commands[1] = "exploit";
    commands[2] = "set";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nextCommand;



    System.out.println("Welcome to Wax!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    do{
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Wax >");
        nextCommand= s.next();
            if (Arrays.asList(commands).contains(nextCommand)){
            if (commands[0]==nextCommand){
                cm.deauth();







            }else{
            System.out.println("Cannot find command, try again.");
            }

        }
    }while(1==1);

}


}
```

and the other classes are not important. I need to know how to make a loop that will work with the context I am using it for. I do not have any experience with Command Line Interface programming. I also want to make this from scratch. So if any of you guys have a suggestion please help me.

Comment: Sorry, it's totally unclear what you're asking. StackOverflow is for Q&A, not general code feedback. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can't restructure this into a question with a concrete answer.

Comment: Sorry i'll write that question again.

Comment: are you aware of Apache CLI? See: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/ - it has some very common features available so one does not need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your reply with your new question. I would suggest editing your original question instead of answering yourself with your updated question. You said you wanted to get user input, execute a command, then ask for input again. You can do that by making a getCommand() function to get the input from the user:

```
public static String getCommand() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean containsCommand;
    String nextCommand;
    do {
        nextCommand = s.nextLine();
        containsCommand = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
            if (commands[i].equals(nextCommand) {
                containsCommand = true;
                return nextCommand;
            }    
        } 
        if (!containsCommand) {
            System.out.println("please enter valid option");
        }
    while(!containsCommand); 
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
while (!exitFlag) {
    String command = getCommand();
    if (command.equals("commandOne")) {
        //do command one stuff
    } // else if...
}
```

This will get the command, run the command, then loop back into get command. Note this loop could run forever so I'd recommend adding a way to set an exit flag.

Comment: I am rewriting the question right now.

Comment: Thanks man! Had to debug it a lot but now works!

Comment: I do not know where do you take the !exitFlag boolean but ok